# What does L EQU 0AH and T EQU 09H mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, tasm

Can someone explain what each expression(L Equ 0AH and T equ 09h) means in assembly,please?

Comment: L is short for Line Feed (0ah) and T is short for Tab character (09h).

Comment: And EQU , 0AH and 09H?

Comment: It is like saying `#define L 0x0a` and `#define T 0x09` in _C_. You can then use L and T instead of the actual values. You can check an [ASCII chart](https://www.bibase.com/ascii.htm) to see the hex to character mappings

Comment: Googling "tasm directives documentation" did return some PDF file with official documentation (which is BTW part of the turbo assembler package, when you buy it). You can check directives description there.

Answer (score 1):

They set symbolic names `L` and `T` equal to literal values.  Effectively, wherever `L` appears in the code, it will be replaced by the assembler by `0x0a`.  In other words, this is defining static, constant values, not allocating memory for a variable.